# Is there an in memory database that supports the DATE function?

Tags: unit-testing, postgresql

I am doing some unit testing for a DAO that works with postgresql. Some of the SQL queries that my DAO uses involve the DATE function. Is there an in-memory database that supports functions similar to the ones that postgresql does?

Currently I am looking for support for the DATE function however, I obviously can see myself using other functions in the future.

Comment: Out of curiosity - what kind of DATE function are you talking about? (a link to the approriate page in the Postgres manual would be helpful.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sqlite3 has [in-memory](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) support, and it has [DATE functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the TimesTen In-Memory Database as well.  Very fast and has `TO_DATE` function:

```
Command> SELECT TO_DATE ('1999, JAN 14', 'YYYY, MON DD') FROM dual;
< 1999-01-14 00:00:00 >
1 row found.
```

Answer (score 0):

In linux you can create an "in memory database" with postgresql using a ramdisk. Quoting from [a thread](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2008-11/msg00757.php) in postgresql mailing list:

> In my opinion very nice solution is
>   building part of PostgreSQL database
>   in memory - below it is instruction
>   how to build PostgreSQL schema in
>   memory in Linux. I tested this with my
>   ROLAP solution for recalculation MOLAP
>   cubes in memory and then join with
>   master cube (this speeds up proces
>   about 10 times!!! - but in other
>   solution may be different).
>
> In grub (or other bootloader) you must
>   declare ramdisk and then in OS:

```
mke2fs /dev/ram0
mkdir /mnt/ram0
mount /dev/ram0 /mnt/ram0
mkdir /mnt/ram0/pgspace
chown postgres:postgres mnt/ram0/pgspace
```

> The "/mnt/ram0/pgspace" folder must be
>   empty (ERROR:  directory "/mnt/ram0"
>   is not empty)
>
> And  then you may create tables (in
>   this schema of course) and write to
>   them.

I didn't tried this, I'm not 100% sure that this works without problems. Note also that in the same thread they suggest other db engine with in memory support, but no mention about `DATE` function. Other rdbms could benefit from ramdisk also if they have support for  table space.

**EDIT**

Ex:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE inram LOCATION '/mnt/ram0/pgspace';
CREATE TABLE foo(i int) TABLESPACE inram;
```

`foo` table now should be an in-memory table.

Comment: I don't really see how this could be applied to unit testing though.

Comment: @Chris J: I hope I better answer your question. Anyway this would be an "that one is the one for you, this one is just an alternative" answer.